# Why is my query only searching for names that start and end with a and neglecting the names that start and end with m?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select plantcode, plantname 
from `plant` 
where plantname like 'a%a' or 'm%m';
```

after I execute the query, it gets only the names that start and end with a from my database, while I also asked for words that also start and end with m!

Comment: You need `WHERE platname LIKE 'a%a' OR platname LIKE 'm%m'`

Comment: already tried that, it shows then only the words that start and end with m

Answer (score 1):

That's just a wrong syntax - having `or m%m` in the end without a matching column won't yield the expected result. You have to repeat that `plantname`:

```
select plantcode, plantname 
from `plant` 
where plantname like 'a%a' or plantname like 'm%m';
```

Comment: i also did that, it then neglects the words that start and end with a!

Comment: nvm it worked, thanks

Comment: and to display names that have only 5 letters or more?

Comment: Please open a new question if you want to ask something else